# MPMoviePlayerViewController plays on simulator, device, Test Flight, but then crashes once on the App Store

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am having an issue where an MP4 I'm playing using MPMoviePlayerViewController is crashing my app when the app is downloaded through the App Store. This same video and same build plays fine when run on the simulator through xcode, when run on a device through xcode, and when installed on a device via Test Flight.

I have confirmed that the MP4 file is included in Build Phases -> Copy Bundle Resources.

I'm relatively new to xCode, but having had a peek at the crash report I believe there is a problem with the fileURLWithPath I'm using, but since it works everywhere except once finally on the App Store, I'm having trouble figuring out where I went wrong.

Here is the code I'm using to show the video:

```
- (void)tappedInToolbar:(ReaderMainToolbar *)toolbar videoButton:(UIButton *)button {
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                     pathForResource:@"Welcome-Crossings" ofType:@"mp4"]];
MPMoviePlayerViewController *playercontroller = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc]
                                                 initWithContentURL:url];
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:playercontroller];
playercontroller.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
[playercontroller.moviePlayer play];
playercontroller = nil;
}
```

And here is the Crash report:

```
Incident Identifier: 3D4629BE-B963-4951-A24C-65CE56BA1B34
CrashReporter Key:   96a0c6b17b80f0a7287d9aede092906e03392cb4
Hardware Model:      iPhone7,2
Process:             AppName [4230]
Path:                /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/XXX/AppName.app/AppName
Identifier:          AppIdentifier
Version:             1 (1)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2015-04-02 10:16:57.016 -0400
Launch Time:         2015-04-02 10:16:55.151 -0400
OS Version:          iOS 8.2 (12D508)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x183ede530 __exceptionPreprocess + 132
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x194eb40e4 objc_exception_throw + 60
2   CoreFoundation                  0x183ede470 +[NSException raise:format:] + 128
3   Foundation                      0x184d44c68 -[NSURL(NSURL) initFileURLWithPath:] + 136
4   Foundation                      0x184d44bc8 +[NSURL(NSURL) fileURLWithPath:] + 56
5   AppName 0x100015324 0x100008000 + 54052
6   AppName 0x100027244 0x100008000 + 127556
7   UIKit                           0x188720a14 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 96
8   UIKit                           0x188709d08 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 612
9   UIKit                           0x1887203b0 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 592
10  UIKit                           0x18872003c -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 700
11  UIKit                           0x188719590 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 684
12  UIKit                           0x1886ece60 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 264
13  UIKit                           0x18898c46c _UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent + 15220
14  UIKit                           0x1886eb3d0 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 1716
15  CoreFoundation                  0x183e96d34     __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
16  CoreFoundation                  0x183e95fd8 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 264
17  CoreFoundation                  0x183e94088 __CFRunLoopRun + 712
18  CoreFoundation                  0x183dc11f4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 396
19  GraphicsServices                0x18d1e36fc GSEventRunModal + 168
20  UIKit                           0x18875210c UIApplicationMain + 1488
21  AppName 0x100025f6c 0x100008000 + 122732
22  libdyld.dylib                   0x195532a08 start + 4


Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019564b270 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001956e916c pthread_kill + 108
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001955c2b14 abort + 108
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000194681414 abort_message + 112
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001946a0b88 default_terminate_handler() + 300
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000194eb43bc _objc_terminate() + 124
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000019469dbb0 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 12
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000019469d738 __cxa_rethrow + 140
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000194eb4290 objc_exception_rethrow + 40
9   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183dc12a0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 568
10  GraphicsServices                0x000000018d1e36f8 GSEventRunModal + 164
11  UIKit                           0x0000000188752108 UIApplicationMain + 1484
12  ...AppName  0x0000000100025f68 0x100008000 + 122728
13  libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000195532a04 start + 0

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000195630c24 kevent64 + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000195515e6c _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 272
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000195507998 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 48

Thread 2 name:  Dispatch queue: ReaderThumbWorkQueue :: NSOperation 0x174055600
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000195630e0c mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000195630c84 mach_msg + 68
2   IOKit                           0x00000001850c5eb0 io_connect_method + 360
3   IOKit                           0x0000000185076078 IOConnectCallMethod + 228
4   IOSurface                       0x000000018d8b2fc8 IOSurfaceClientWrapClientImage + 464
5   IOSurface                       0x000000018d8b570c IOSurfaceWrapClientImage + 16
6   ImageIO                         0x000000018519e0b0 createImageIOSurfaceWithFormat + 128
7   ImageIO                         0x000000018516adf4 createImageBlockSetWithAspenHardwareDecode + 544
8   ImageIO                         0x000000018519a6a8 copyImageBlockSetAppleJPEG + 5028
9   ImageIO                         0x00000001850eb20c ImageProviderCopyImageBlockSetCallback + 780
10  CoreGraphics                    0x0000000184134030 img_blocks_create + 372
11  CoreGraphics                    0x0000000184125404 img_data_lock + 1288
12  CoreGraphics                    0x00000001841244ec CGSImageDataLock + 136
13  libRIP.A.dylib                  0x00000001844dd72c ripc_AcquireImage + 768
14  libRIP.A.dylib                  0x00000001844dcb00 ripc_DrawImage + 600
15  CoreGraphics                    0x000000018412421c CGContextDrawImage + 404
16  CoreGraphics                    0x0000000184218450 CGPDFDrawingContextDrawImage + 292
17  CoreGraphics                    0x000000018420ae38 op_Do + 148
18  CoreGraphics                    0x0000000184249290 pdf_scanner_handle_xname + 112
19  CoreGraphics                    0x0000000184248afc CGPDFScannerScan + 268
20  CoreGraphics                    0x00000001841d1acc CGPDFDrawingContextDrawPage + 436
21  CoreGraphics                    0x0000000184237ab8 pdf_page_draw_in_context + 104
22  CoreGraphics                    0x00000001841c99b8 CGContextDrawPDFPage + 44
23  ...AppName  0x000000010000cee0 0x100008000 + 20192
24  Foundation                      0x0000000184cfcec8 -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] + 632
25  Foundation                      0x0000000184dbe948 __NSOQSchedule_f + 224
26  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000195505950 _dispatch_client_callout + 12
27  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001955100a0 _dispatch_queue_drain + 1444
28  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000195508a58 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 128
29  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000195512314 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 716
30  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000195513c48 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 104
31  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001956e5228 _pthread_wqthread + 812
32  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001956e4eec start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019564bc78 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001956e52d8 _pthread_wqthread + 988
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001956e4eec start_wqthread + 0

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019564bc78 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001956e52d8 _pthread_wqthread + 988
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001956e4eec start_wqthread + 0

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019564bc78 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001956e52d8 _pthread_wqthread + 988
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001956e4eec start_wqthread + 0

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019564bc78 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001956e52d8 _pthread_wqthread + 988
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001956e4eec start_wqthread + 0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x00000001740f2137
    x4: 0x00000001946a1dfd   x5: 0x000000016fdf7370   x6: 0x000000000000006e   x7: 0x0000000000000580
    x8: 0x0000000008000000   x9: 0x0000000004000000  x10: 0x0000000000000200  x11: 0x0000000000000000
   x12: 0x0000000000000000  x13: 0x0000000000000000  x14: 0x0000000000000002  x15: 0x0000000000000000
   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x0000000000000000  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
   x20: 0x00000001996a3310  x21: 0x000000019968bce8  x22: 0x000000017415eaf0  x23: 0x0000000195b4bc80
   x24: 0x0000000000000001  x25: 0x000000017415eae0  x26: 0x000000019968a0a8  x27: 0x0000000000000001
   x28: 0x0000000000000000  fp: 0x000000016fdf72d0   lr: 0x00000001956e9170
sp: 0x000000016fdf72b0   pc: 0x000000019564b270 cpsr: 0x00000000
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: check if file exists first. Lot of people having problems with the files being gone when uploading to appstore.

Comment: Hi Jaro, thanks for your reply.

How might I check the file? This video file is included in the app bundle, I have confirmed it has an entry in "Copy Bundle Resources", and as I mentioned it plays on the app when I download the same build through Test Flight. It seems to ONLY be missing once published to the App Store. The crash report above suggests the file is missing, but is there a way to confirm or refute that?

Thanks again.